# How to unlock screen with Bluetooth keyboard

Tags: 8.1-oreo

I can wake up the screen of my Android device by hitting almost any key on my bluetooth keyboard.  But all I see are my notifications, I can't actually unlock the screen.  How do I get the thing to come up that lets me enter the numbers of my PIN to unlock my screen?  Is there a setting somewhere that I a missing that would allow me to just start typing my PIN instead of ignoring what I type?

I'm running stock Android 8.1 on a Google phone.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue... two parts to my solution... 
- set Smartlock to unlock phone when BT keyboard connects
- then any key wakes to Notifications screen... then 'space-tab' key combination opens the phone to current android screen... found by trial and error!